# Remove extra double quotes in generated JSON string from fetched DB results

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have searched Google that might answer my question but then I came into a dead brain.

I have some JSON output from my query

```
$myQuery = "SELECT title, start FROM reserved_b";
$result = $mysqli->query($myQuery) or die($mysqli->error);
$data = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
   $data[] = json_encode($row);
}

$json = json_encode($data);
echo $str = str_replace('\\', '', $json);
```

then this is the result

```
["{"title":"Wedding","start":"2015-01-29 00:00:00"}","{"title":"Gathering","start":"2015-01-23 01:00:00"}"]
```

I just want to remove the double quotes, and the output should be like this:

```
[{"title":"Wedding","start":"2015-01-29 00:00:00"},{"title":"Gathering","start":"2015-01-23 01:00:00"}]
```

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't use string operations `(str_replace)` to solve this problem. The reason why your JSON string is not well constructed is because you have a superfluous/unneeded encoding while inside the loop.

Just finish creating the array structure, then finally encode:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT title, start FROM reserved_b";
$result = $mysqli->query($myQuery) or die($mysqli->error);
$data = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $data[] = $row; // just push it as an array
}
// then finally, encode in the end
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
```

Comment: WHAT THE HELL.. how foolish i am.. :'(

Thank you for blazing fast answer.. until i cannot click this accepted answer

Comment: @SyarifHidayatullahLubis yes, thats what you would do normally, create the final array first, then you encode it in the end, then you'll have a properly constructed json string. glad this helped

Comment: Thank you for saving me from painful day into a nice one